# How to remove the dots from custom menu with CSS

Tags: css

I want to remove(hide) bullets (dots) with css code, but I can`t
Please tell me what I do wrong:
1) I give class name in my case: .no-bullets
2) I use this css code:

```
.no-bullets {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

this is not working for me...

Then I use this css in theme stylesheet:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

again nothing...

Please help me with this, thank you in advance

Comment: seemed to work for me  https://jsfiddle.net/fog63gjm/1/

Comment: Probably you have imported another CSS file after this which overrides ul style.

Comment: yeah but on my site is not working...

Comment: Ali - no this is the only css that I use at the moment...

Comment: @svet Link us to the site? I'll debug it quickly for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `list-style` properties apply to elements with `display: list-item` only ,make sure your list elements doesnt have any other `display` style.
UPDATE
seeing your link your `style.css` file is overriding your custom style with `list-style-type: disc;` you have to get rid of this line.

UPDATE 2
use this code in your custom css 
 `.entry-content ul > li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}`

 this will do the job quickly.

Comment: so the css is : .no-bullets {
    list-style-type: disc; 
}  ? its not working...

Comment: is 'style.css' your only css file ? if so, go to line 1462 and remove 'list-style-type: disc' then style of class '.no-bullets { list-style-type: none; } ' would work as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: noob question - how to see 1462 line - in wordpress? Or if I have to use cpanel - where to go for this line - file? Ty

Comment: yes, open file **style.css** with an editor like notepad++ for example, and in line 1462 there is **list-style-type: disc;** which you have to remove it. and simply those annoying dots will go away!

Comment: looking at your html tag you have **<link rel="stylesheet" id="altitude-pro-theme-css" href="http://www.gerylaskova.com/wp-content/themes/altitude-pro/style.css?ver=1.0.2" type="text/css" media="all">** which loaded style.css in your website, so you cant modify it unless you download it and link it manually to your website then you can modify it , but for a quicker solution i updated my answer.

Comment: thank you again I delete the line and now its ok, ty once again

Comment: well glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

here is my suggestion:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;}
```